Script-proposed safe transactions are not shown in SAFE UI
I have a problem with the safe ui on linea.
We successfully proposed a transaction using a script (that uses @safe-global/protocol-kit).
The UI does not show any pending transactions in the queue. But when I run our other script that pulls the proposals and allows us to sign them without the UI, then it returns the proposed transaction.
So it seems that the UI has an issue and does not display correct data.
This is our safe address on linea:
linea:0xdf61270fDC1A892874Fd3C0143A0A4CBA74F4EF1
Please could you have a look at this issue?
Empty queue on UI:

Proposal is correctly displayed when running our script and pulling pending proposals:


Can you check transactions appear on https://safe-transaction-linea.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xdf61270fDC1A892874Fd3C0143A0A4CBA74F4EF1/multisig-transactions/ after you propose them?

Transactions that are proposed without any signatures at all will not be displayed in the UI. Is this the case in your script? If you are able and willing to share it, it will also help us debug the problem. Thanks in advance
